# Ruby on Rails -- javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rating-system

I need to implement Star Rating system to let `users` rate `hotels`. I took [this tutorial](http://camjuarez.com/posts/star-rating-system-with-ajax-and-remote-forms) as the example.

**rating.js** file is:

```
$(function() {
  $('.rating_star').click(function() {
    var star = $(this);
    var form_id = star.attr("data-form-id");
    var stars = star.attr("data-stars");
    $('#' + form_id + '_stars').val(stars);

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: $('#' + form_id).attr('action') + '.json',
      data: $('#' + form_id).serialize(),
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        update_stars();
        if(response["avg_rating"]){
          $('#average_rating').text(response["avg_rating"]);
          }
        }
      })
  });        
});

function update_stars(){
  $('.star_rating_form').each(function() {
    var form_id = $(this).attr('id');
    set_stars(form_id, $('#' + form_id + '_stars').val());
  });
}

function set_stars(form_id, stars) {
  for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    if(i <= stars){
      $('#' + form_id + '_' + i).addClass("on");
    } else {
      $('#' + form_id + '_' + i).removeClass("on");
    }
  }
}
```

But this code doesn't work, because when I mouse-on or click the stars, nothing happens at all... I think the error is somewhere in the java code, because testing javascript file works fine. But I can't find this error.

PS: **ratings_controller.rb**

```
  before_filter :js_logged_in

  def create
    @rating = Rating.new(params[:rating])
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:rating][:hotel_id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @rating.save
          format.json { render :json => { :avg_rating => @hotel.avg_rating } }
        else
          format.json { render :json => @rating.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
  end

  def update
    @rating = Rating.find(params[:id])
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:rating][:hotel_id])
    @rating.update_attributes(params[:rating])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rating.save
        format.json { render :json => { :avg_rating => @hotel.avg_rating } }
      else
        format.json { render :json => @rating.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def rating_params
    params.require(:rating).permit(:stars)
  end

  private

    def js_logged_in
      if(!signed_in?)
      flash[:error] = "You must be a signed in to leave a rating!"
      render :js => "window.location = '/signin'"
    end
end
```

Source of the page with rating stars consists this line:

`<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/rating.js?body=1"></script>`

**UPD1:** Output of the rails error log showed me that I missed an `end` statement... After I added it the error changed:

```
Started PATCH "/ratings/2.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-19 18:52:43 +0400
Processing by RatingsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7DwBNYlmmucwodZ8UDINYIaMG8Ep4sloBGEoiaiXoxQ=", "rating"=>{"hotel_id"=>"10", "user_id"=>"1", "stars"=>"5"}, "id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '715016a7327649b3aaeb6f7e65b10996cbe1eb08' LIMIT 1
  Rating Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ratings".* FROM "ratings"  WHERE "ratings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Hotel Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "hotels".* FROM "hotels"  WHERE "hotels"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
  app/controllers/ratings_controller.rb:20:in `update'


  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (5.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (72.6ms)
```

Error appears to be in rating_controller in the next line:

```
@rating.update_attributes(params[:rating])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I think the error is exactly in the java code"? What is the output of browser console? Are there any JS errors?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'somewhere'. No, there are no errors in console.

Comment: Is `ajax` works and what address and parameters goes on server? You can see it in the `Network` section.

Comment: Can you show the console log for this error?

Comment: When I click on the star, network section has following: 
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000

Request URL:http://localhost:3000/ratings/2.json 

Request Method:POST

Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Comment: What is your Rails log output?

Comment: Check your rails console as well to see what errors you may have

Comment: I created a hotel in console, and there wasn't any errors (checked with errors.full_messages). Is that what I should've done? Sorry if not...

Comment: No. Output of `tail -f log/development.log` when you have this error.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear.  The running error log is what i meant.  Basically the terminal window where you write 'rails server'  When you click the star you are getting an internal server error.  Let us know if there are error in that log

Comment: tail -f log/development.log : from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
 from bin/rails:8:in `require'
 from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'

Comment: @AlMacks please paste whole output in question.

Comment: Thank you all guys for leading me to an answer! And I'm sorry that it was hard enough. I learned much from solving this issue, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting indicates you've missed an `end` statement at the end of the your file.

This is likely because your indenting is wrong, and has presumably has lead to unbalanced `end` statements.

Here is the end of your file:

```
  def js_logged_in
    if(!signed_in?)
    flash[:error] = "You must be a signed in to leave a rating!"
    render :js => "window.location = '/signin'"
  end
end
```

That final `end` doesn't close the class definition, it closes `def js_logged_in` method. You didn't indent the body of your `if`, the `end` that matches your `def js_logged_in` is actually closing the `if`.

Comment: You're right, but there is a new mistake now (after I added 'end').

Comment: UPD ...and it gone when I changed the line into this: **@rating.update_attributes(rating_params)**. Thank you!